# Reaction of propanoic acid with chlorine used in wastewater treatment

Tags: organic-chemistry, water-treatment, halogens

I'm asked in a problem to write down the equation of the reaction of propanoic acid with chlorine used in wastewater treatment: $\ce{CH3-CH2-COOH +Cl2}$. The problem also states that, in this reaction, $\ce{CO2}$ and chlorides are produced.

I have searched about it and I have found that there is a reaction of propanoic acid with chlorine called *chlorination process*, but it does not fit with the products that the problem specifies should be produced...

What would this reaction be?

Comment: The main reaction is a free radical chlorination which is catalysed by light which splits the chlorine molecule to deliver 2 highly reactive Cl radicals. One of these adds to the 2 position of propanoic acid generating a hydrogen radical which combines with the 2nd chlorine radical to give HCl. The 2-chloropropanoic acid can also decarboxylate giving CO2 and chloroethane.

Comment: @Waylander. What do you consider the mechanism for the decarboxylation of 2-chloropropanoic acid  to CO2 and chloroethane?

Comment: @user55119  struggling to find one. Have you got any suggestions?

Comment: @Waylander. The information provided is rather vague. What chlorides are formed? At this time I would guess some form of radical process. Who knows?

Comment: @user55119 I would think it has to be. I cannot account for the production of CO2 any other way.

Comment: @Waylander: One might imagine additional beta-radical chlorination. Decarboxylation with loss of the beta-chlorine could lead to a number of perchloroethylenes. They sound like more of a pollution problem than propanoic acid.